# Skip to next host in array if an error is thrown

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array which is populated with IP addresses. Now say I have a method that tries to connect to each host in the array. In this particular instance I don't need to know any details about the failed connections, I just want to skip to the next host if one fails to connect or if ANY errors are thrown. How do I do this?

The problem I'm having is that, occasionally, when connecting to one of the hosts the program will throw an ENETUNREACH error and then kill the program. I tried solving it by just rescuing the error, but then what happens is the program will just stop executing without throwing any errors. How do I get it to skip the host in the array, and just move on to the next host?

```
def popen(host)
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(host, nil)
    sock = Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)

    begin
        sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))

    rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS
        resp = IO.select(nil, [sock], nil, @timeout.to_i)

        if resp.nil?
            false 
        end

        begin
            if sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))
                sshlog(host, @user, @pass)
            end

        rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
            false
        end
    end
    sock
end
```

That is the connect method. And this:

```
    def randIP
    begin
        threads = []

        if @arg1 =~ /^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)$/
            t1 = Time.now

            s = 1

            while s <= @arg1.to_i do
                @host_arr << Array.new(4){rand(254)}.join('.')
                s += 1
            end

            @host_arr.each do |ip|
                threads << Thread.new do
                    begin
                        popen(ip)
                    rescue Errno::ENETUNREACH
                    end
                end
            end

            threads.each do |thread|
                thread.join
            end

            t2 = Time.now
            time = t2 - t1
            STDOUT.puts "done"

            proxylst(@res_arr, @user, @pass)

        else
            puts "Host range too large! Must be a number between 1 and 1000."
        end

    rescue
       false
    end
end
```

Is a method that generates random IP addresses, puts them into an array, and uses the popen method above to attempt a connection on each host. Considering the nature of random IP address generation, chances are at least one out of 1000 hosts is going to be either invalid, or unreachable in some way. So what I need is a way to try *every* host in the array skipping any that throw errors.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to try an connect to an ip. Writing a method that checks if it can ping it isn't going to solve your problem

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited OP with code.

Answer (score 0):

typically how I handle this is like so:

```
exception_array = []
Connections.each do |con|
  begin
    #connection code
  rescue Exception => e
    exception_array << e
  end
end

unless exception_array.empty?
msg = ""
  exception_array.each do |e|
    msg << e.to_s
  end
  raise msg
end
```

This way you keep track of all exceptions that were thrown without breaking the code on a failure.

Comment: I solved this by adding next into my popen(ip) loop. I was putting next in the wrong place. Thanks everyone.